# How to make grid of the irregular data?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I have the numpy arrays of longitudes, latitudes, and the data.
I want to plot this data as a raster image using numpy, scipy, and matplotlib.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

longitudes = np.array([[139.79391479492188, 140.51760864257812, 141.19119262695312, 141.82083129882812, 142.41165161132812],
        [139.79225158691406, 140.51416015625, 141.18606567382812, 141.8140869140625, 142.40338134765625],
        [139.78591918945312, 140.50637817382812, 141.17694091796875, 141.80377197265625, 142.3919677734375],
        [139.78387451171875, 140.50253295898438, 141.17147827148438, 141.79678344726562, 142.38360595703125],
        [139.77781677246094, 140.4949951171875, 141.16250610351562, 141.78646850585938, 142.37196350097656]],dtype=float)


latitudes =  np.array([[55.61929702758789, 55.621070861816406, 55.61888122558594, 55.613487243652344, 55.60547637939453],
             [55.53120040893555, 55.532840728759766, 55.53053665161133, 55.525047302246094, 55.5169677734375],
             [55.44305419921875, 55.444580078125, 55.44219207763672, 55.43663024902344, 55.42848587036133],
             [55.35470199584961, 55.356109619140625, 55.353614807128906, 55.34796905517578, 55.33975601196289],
             [55.26683807373047, 55.268131256103516, 55.26553726196289, 55.25981140136719, 55.25152587890625]],dtype=float)

data =  np.array([[10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
        [20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
        [30, 30, 30, 30, 30],
        [40, 40, 40, 40, 40],
        [50, 50, 50, 50, 50]],dtype=float)


x = longitudes.ravel()
y = latitudes.ravel()
z = data.ravel()

xMin, xMax = np.min(x), np.max(x)
yMin, yMax = np.min(y), np.max(y)

xi = np.linspace(xMin, xMax, 0.005)  ##choosen spacing of 0.005
yi = np.linspace(yMin, yMax, 0.005)  ##choosen spacing of 0.005
```

The data are not exactly a grid. Actually I could not imagine how to do it ahead:

```
zi_matplotlib = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi, interp='linear')

from scipy.interpolate import griddata  ##Using scipy method

zi_scipy = griddata((x, y), z, (xi, yi), method='nearest')    

plt.imshow(????)
```

Any ideas and solution please.

Comment: What do you mean that you "I could not imagine ahead", and why do you need the fastest way? And have you looked at scipy's `interp2d` for solving this?

Comment: scipy's interp2d seems good, trying to do..

Comment: I've used this before, might also be interesting for you: https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/regulargrid

Comment: @tom10 Does not imshow with interpolation method as hitzg used does not include the same method as you mentioned with interp2d?

Comment: scipy has more interpolation methods and more flexibility. For example, scipy has methods that don't require the data to be on a regular grid, and there are other flexibilities as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use interpolation to convert the distorted grid into a regular grid.  The interpolation fits the original data points and returns a function that can be evaluated at any point of your choosing, and in this case, you would choose a regular grid of points.

Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# your data here, as posted in the question

f = interp2d(lon, lat, data, kind="cubic", bounds_error=False)

dlon, dlat = 1.2, .2
xlon = np.linspace(min(lon.flat), max(lon.flat), 20)
xlat = np.linspace(min(lat.flat), max(lat.flat), 20)

# the next few lines are because there seems to be a bug in interp2d
#  instead one would just want to use   r = interp2d(X.flat, Y.flat) (where X,Y are as below)
#  but for the version of scipy I'm using ('0.13.3'), this throws an exception.
r = np.zeros((len(xlon), len(xlat)))
for i, rlat in enumerate(xlat):
    for j, rlon in enumerate(xlon):
        r[i,j] = f(rlon, rlat)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(xlon, xlat)
plt.imshow(r, interpolation="nearest", origin="lower", extent=[min(xlon), max(xlon), min(xlat), max(xlat)], aspect=6.)

plt.scatter(lon.flat, lat.flat, color='k')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Here, I left the mesh fairly coarse (20x20) and used `interpolation="nearest"` so you could still see the colored squares representing each of the interpolated values, done, of course, on a regular grid (created using the two `linspace` calls).  Note also the use or `origin="lower"` which sets the image and the scatter plot to have the same orientation.

To interpret this, the main issue is that changing of values from left-to-right.  This is due to the data being specified as constant across the horizontal set of points, but because the points where these specified were warped, the interpolated values slowly change as they move across.  For example, the lowest scatter point on the right should have approximately the same color as the highest one towards the left.  Also, indicative of this is that there's not much color change between any of the two leftmost pairs, but a lot between the two right most, where the warping is largest.

Note that the interpolation could be done for any values, not only a regular grid, which is just being used for `imshow` as per the original question.  Also note that I used `bounds_error=False` so I could evaluate a few points slightly outside of the original dataset, but be very careful with this as points outside of the original data will quickly become unreasonable due to the cubics being evaluated beyond the region where they were fit.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `longitudes` and `latitudes` are equally spaced, you can use `imshow` directly as it features interpolation:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

longitudes = np.array([[139.79391479492188, 140.51760864257812, 141.19119262695312, 141.82083129882812, 142.41165161132812],
        [139.79225158691406, 140.51416015625, 141.18606567382812, 141.8140869140625, 142.40338134765625],
        [139.78591918945312, 140.50637817382812, 141.17694091796875, 141.80377197265625, 142.3919677734375],
        [139.78387451171875, 140.50253295898438, 141.17147827148438, 141.79678344726562, 142.38360595703125],
        [139.77781677246094, 140.4949951171875, 141.16250610351562, 141.78646850585938, 142.37196350097656]],dtype=float)


latitudes =  np.array([[55.61929702758789, 55.621070861816406, 55.61888122558594, 55.613487243652344, 55.60547637939453],
             [55.53120040893555, 55.532840728759766, 55.53053665161133, 55.525047302246094, 55.5169677734375],
             [55.44305419921875, 55.444580078125, 55.44219207763672, 55.43663024902344, 55.42848587036133],
             [55.35470199584961, 55.356109619140625, 55.353614807128906, 55.34796905517578, 55.33975601196289],
             [55.26683807373047, 55.268131256103516, 55.26553726196289, 55.25981140136719, 55.25152587890625]],dtype=float)

data =  np.array([[10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
        [20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
        [30, 30, 30, 30, 30],
        [40, 40, 40, 40, 40],
        [50, 50, 50, 50, 50]],dtype=float)

extent = (longitudes[0,0], longitudes[0,-1], latitudes[0,0], latitudes[-1,0])
plt.imshow(data, interpolation='bilinear', extent=extent, aspect='auto')
plt.show()
```

I'm aware that this does not *exactly* answer your question. But I think it is an easy solution to the underlying problem.

---

### Edit

I just realized that your data is in fact not exactly a grid, but almost. You have to decide if you still want to use my solution...

Comment: Thanks for your attempt. Yes, the data are not exactly a grid, so I first want to make it grid.Then your solution to plotting seems helpful(upvoted!)

Comment: The issue with using imshow is that it assumes regularly spaced data coordinates which cannot be assumed for geographic coordinates. This is why pcolormesh is usually recommended over imshow.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a scatter 3d plot using your data, breaking out each set of lat/long data in its own series with respective colored markers.

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


longitudes = np.array([[139.79391479492188, 140.51760864257812, 141.19119262695312, 141.82083129882812, 142.41165161132812],
        [139.79225158691406, 140.51416015625, 141.18606567382812, 141.8140869140625, 142.40338134765625],
        [139.78591918945312, 140.50637817382812, 141.17694091796875, 141.80377197265625, 142.3919677734375],
        [139.78387451171875, 140.50253295898438, 141.17147827148438, 141.79678344726562, 142.38360595703125],
        [139.77781677246094, 140.4949951171875, 141.16250610351562, 141.78646850585938, 142.37196350097656]],dtype=float)


latitudes =  np.array([[55.61929702758789, 55.621070861816406, 55.61888122558594, 55.613487243652344, 55.60547637939453],
             [55.53120040893555, 55.532840728759766, 55.53053665161133, 55.525047302246094, 55.5169677734375],
             [55.44305419921875, 55.444580078125, 55.44219207763672, 55.43663024902344, 55.42848587036133],
             [55.35470199584961, 55.356109619140625, 55.353614807128906, 55.34796905517578, 55.33975601196289],
             [55.26683807373047, 55.268131256103516, 55.26553726196289, 55.25981140136719, 55.25152587890625]],dtype=float)

data =  np.array([[10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
        [20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
        [30, 30, 30, 30, 30],
        [40, 40, 40, 40, 40],
        [50, 50, 50, 50, 50]],dtype=float)

colors = ['r','g','b','k','k']
markers = ['o','o','o','o','^']

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

for i in range(5):
    ax.scatter(longitudes[i], latitudes[i], data[i], c=colors[i], marker=markers[i])

ax.set_xlabel('Longitude')
ax.set_ylabel('Latitude')
ax.set_zlabel('Data')

plt.show()
```

Which results in an image like

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your 3d plot which shows how the data is distributing. But my question is about creating 2d raster image from the data. The x and y axis of the 2d image will be longitudes and latitides, but they are put in the regular grid by interpolating the given irrigular data.